# Using .NET dll with ComVisible(false) in unmanaged c++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, dll, com

I am trying to use a third-party dll that I do not have the source code for.  I have successfully made use of it in VC++ when compiling with /clr.  However, I wanted to make use of it in an unmanaged c++ application, without compiling with /clr.  When I looked at the dll in the Visual Studio object bowser I noticed that the attributes for the assembly were listed as:

```
Attributes:
System.CLSCompliantAttribute(true),
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(false),
System.Reflection.AssemblyDelaySignAttribute(false),
System.Reflection.AssemblyKeyNameAttribute(""),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SuppressIldasmAttribute,
System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Retail"),
System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute(0),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute,
```

As ComVisible is false I am unable to obtain the type library and am not sure how I can use this dll in a native c++ program.  Is is possible to do this at all?

Comment: Well, if you want to use COM to do this then just write your own wrapper classes in C# that are [ComVisible].  Hosting the CLR yourself is the general solution.

Comment: Ahh yes, I should have thought about that myself.  I think a simple wrapper that exposes the classes I requires should be ok.  I will try doing that.